# Mysql data in desired format and table

Tags: mysql

I m having a database named lumia and inside that database i have several tables   which gets updated with current date & time when a link is fired. I have given the link of mysql dump file at the end .

I want data in following format:-

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| TC       |      Play  |   Skip   |
+----------+------------+----------+
| blr      |        132 |    33    |
| Chen     |        133 |    3     |
+----------+------------+----------+
```

in which Play column will contain the counts of rows of blr_play_dt and skip column will contain the counts of rows of blr_skip_dt and so on and TC will contain blr, chen and so on i am having the following mysql query:-

```
 SELECT
     'blr_play' AS table_label,
     COUNT(*) AS table_size
 FROM
     blr_play
UNION
     SELECT
       'blr_skip' AS table_label,

        COUNT(*) AS table_size
    FROM
         blr_skip
```

but its giving results like this

```
 +----------+------------+
 | TC       | table_size |
 +----------+------------+
 | blr_play |        132 |
 | blr_skip |         33 |
 | chen_play|        124 |
 | chen_skip|          2 |
 +----------+------------+
```

and i want the above data in this format:-

```
+----------+------------+----------+
| TC       |      Play  |   Skip   |
+----------+------------+----------+
| blr      |        132 |    33    |
| Chen     |        124 |    2     |
+----------+------------+----------+
```

Link for the sql dump file :- https://www.mediafire.com/?444n3tvcvj24dpm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a sub query:

```
 SELECT
      'blr' AS table_label,
      COUNT(*) AS playCnt,
      (select count(*) from blr_skip) as skipCnt
FROM  blr_play
```

It looks like you have a table for each TC ? so for chen also:

```
 SELECT
      'blr' AS table_label,
      COUNT(*) AS playCnt,
      (select count(*) from blr_skip) as skipCnt
FROM  blr_play
UNION ALL
 SELECT
      'Chen' AS table_label,
      COUNT(*) AS playCnt,
      (select count(*) from Chen_skip) as skipCnt
FROM  Chen_play
```

EDIT: sounds like you are looking for conditional aggregation  -

```
 SELECT
      'blr' AS table_label,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN YourColumn ='2016-03-19' then 1 end) AS playCnt,
      (select count(CASE WHEN YourColumn ='2016-03-19' then 1 end) from blr_skip) as skipCnt
FROM  blr_play
```

When it actually the same as just filtering those result(will perform better)

```
 SELECT
      'blr' AS table_label,
      COUNT(*) AS playCnt,
      (select count(*) from blr_skip WHERE YourColumn ='2016-03-19') as skipCnt
FROM  blr_play 
WHERE YourColumn ='2016-03-19'
```

Comment: thanks it really works but one more thing i want to filter it datewise like i want to count the rows which have "2016-03-19".

Comment: @sonadas I've updated the answer, will appreciate an approval if it helped you

Comment: Thankyou Very much for your help i appreciate it you are a life saver it works as i needed but can't we set the time globally in the query because i have to UNION other tables also.